# How to copy from excel multine cells without quote duplication?

Tags: excel, vba

When I paste it into any editor, quotes appear at the end and at beginning, and the quotes inside gets duplicated.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what the multiline cell looks like, and what it looks like when you paste it? Also, what specific editor would be helpful.

Comment: For example inside a cell there is a new line.

Comment: Take the tour please

Comment: Please post pictures as an example. This is not a [Minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a macro and try the following code:

```
Sub copy()
    'If needed Attach Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library: tools\references\Browse\FM20.DLL
    'Then set a keyboard shortcut to the CopyCells Macro (eg Crtl T)
    Dim objData As New DataObject
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim concat As String
    Dim cellValue As String
    CR = ""
    For Each cell In Selection
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        cellValue = LTrim(str(cell.Value))
    Else
    cellValue = cell.Value
    End If
    concat = concat + CR + cellValue
    CR = Chr(13)
    Next
    objData.SetText (concat)
    objData.PutInClipboard 
End Sub
```

Comment: An answer just posting code without explaining anything is bad practice. Please read [answer].

Comment: Bad but it was useful

Comment: @Andras_v True, I was just saying: It might be a good idea to add a description what the code does and why it solves the issue. That would almost make it a good answer.